# How can I cancel a Twilio call in iOS after it's been initiated?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, twilio

I'm running into a problem with an app that I'm building that I'm a little stuck on.

I have an iOS app (handles initiating the call via Twilio SDK) that communicates with a Ruby on Rails back-end (handles the Twilio server side implementation) to enable communication between the iDevice and the phone number being called.

The issue I'm having is that when a call is initiated accidentally (user error or misunderstanding how the app works) and the user goes to terminate the call Twilio has already received the request to create the call and it still goes through.

I've tried disabling the TCConnection and the TCDevice using their respective disconnect methods ("disconnect" and "disconnectAll"), but I'm still seeing the call go through (phone number being called still receives the call from the Twilio side of things). I haven't tried anything on the server side of things because I'd like to avoid building a set of "oh &$^$%" protocols if I can avoid it.

Has anyone experienced this before? Does anyone have any suggestions? Is there anyway to terminate calls made accidentally?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have found the Twilio iOS client to be extremely limited when it comes to anything beyond basic functionality. There is no apparent way to handle network failure cases , audio interruptions etc gracefully

Answer (score 0):

Checking back in to share what I've discovered after reaching out to Twilio support in the event anyone finds this in the future.

From Twilio support:

---

For canceling a call, you can use the REST API to modify the live call and set the Status to "completed", which will cancel a ringing call and end an established call:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state

---

So, in short, build some "oh @^%$*" protocols that you can ping as necessary to actively terminate any call that you need to. Not ideal, but the options are limited.